# About RowA, ColA, NulA

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

I have a question regarding matrix subspaces,

I know that - if there is a $v \in ColA$ than there exists $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $v=Ax$

If there is a $v \in NulA$ than $Av=0$

But what can I say if $v \in RowA$ ?

I am asking, because I had a question to prove that for a matrix $A \in \mathbb{M}_{n}$ that satisfy $A=A^2$ than $NulA \cap ColA=${$0$}.

So I took a $v \in NulA \cap ColA$ and I knew that $v \in ColA$ and  $v \in NulA$

And cocnlude that $A(Ax)=0 \implies A^2x=0 \implies Ax=0$ so $v=0$.

So this question made me think what can I say about $v \in RowA$ ?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: It's $Col A$ for the matrix $A^T$.

Comment: Thank you @TSF. I have another question, if I know $detA$, and I know that $A^{-1}$ exists, what can I say about $detA^{-1}$?

Comment: You can say that it's nonzero. It's related to $det A$, and $detA\neq 0$ since $A$ is invertible.

Comment: Great, thank you!

Comment: More particularly, $1 = \det I = \det A^{-1}A = \det A^{-1}\det A$, so $$\det A^{-1} = \frac 1{\det A}$$